# Migrate data from MongoDB to DynamoDB(Localhost)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, data-migration

I need to migrate data from MongoDB to AWS DynamoDB but the condition is we have to migrate it on localhost. It is possible? if yes then please help me and provide needfull article or suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: migrate data or schema? if data, how large is the dataset?

Comment: We want to migrate schema and data both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB is hosted in the cloud, so you would need more than just localhost. You can create a script/executable which reads items/batches from MongoDB and puts them into DynamoDB. This does not work at large scale.

For a proper solution, check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/performing-a-live-migration-from-a-mongodb-cluster-to-amazon-dynamodb/